# MySQL - Duplicate table

Tags: mysql

I need to duplicate a table in MySQL, making the new table empty. That is, I need to copy only the structure of an existing table to a new one.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Try the create table LIKE syntax.

```
create table users2 like users;
```

This should give you an empty table (users2) with the same structure as the original (users).

Comment: thanks sir but how about creating the same table and changing the table type from InnoDB to MYISAM at the same time?

Comment: You'd have to do that in two steps - either run a `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and modify the output to suit you, or run a `CREATE TABLE LIKE` followed by an `ALTER TABLE`.

Answer (score 17):

There is also another way to create a empty table as existing table and you can use the following command also

```
create table a select * from users2 limit 0, 0;
```

Comment: or `CREATE TABLE a SELECT * FROM b WHERE 0=1`

Comment: Just FYI: doing this will NOT copy the indices.