# Is there a way to copy the structure of a table (fields but no data) to a new table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

For example, I have a table named `movies`. It has the fields/columns `title VARCHAR(100)` and `runtime INT(5)`. It's loaded with 10,000 rows of data.

I want to create another table, let's call it `movies_custom`, that has all of the same columns, but with none of the data.

Is there a quick SQL statement to do this?

Comment: I mean MySQL. I will remove that tag.

Comment: Did you try
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/766928/mysql-duplicate-table

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Sorry, I noticed the SQL Server tag on this and assumed that was the technology you were using until I saw MySQL in the question title.

You can use the syntax `CREATE movies_custom LIKE movies` in MySQL

---

Sure!

In SQL Server you can do this query:

```
select top 0 * into movies_custom from movies
```

That creates the table structure without inserting any rows.

Answer (score 1):

Very easy in MySQL:

```
CREATE newtable LIKE oldtable;
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers led me in the right direction, but I had to add the keyword `TABLE` in order to make it work with MySQL Workbench 6.

```
CREATE TABLE movies_custom LIKE movies;
```