# MySQL - Duplicate a Table WITH Triggers

Tags: mysql, copy, sql-like, create-table, database-trigger

I am trying to duplicate a table **with** triggers. I know that I've done this before, I just can't remember how I did it and where I learned how to do it. I've tried `CREATE TABLE newname LIKE oldname` and `CREATE TABLE newname AS oldname`, along with `CREATE TABLE newname SELECT * FROM oldname`. None of those queries seem to be copying triggers. I've followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8226734/how-to-duplicate-a-table-with-keys-other-structure-features-retained-in-mysql), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18017961/duplicate-a-table-including-indexes), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766928/mysql-duplicate-table), and again, no luck. Is there any way that I can copy triggers when duplicating/creating a new table?

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/145042/mysql-create-table-like-include-triggers

Comment: Export the trigger into a textfile. Find and replace the table name. Then import the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is: you cannot do this with a single sql statement.

The reason is that triggers are not part of the table, they are an entirely different object that happens to be related to a table.